# Object mapping design

Tags: c#, oop

I have an C# web application which produces a list of devices stored in our warehouse.

The application has an abstract class called Devices which is used as a base class for all devices in the warehouse for example: TV, Radio, Tablet, MobileTelephone.

The device classes are basically just DTO's - that is no behavior only data.

There is a service which takes the list of devices and maps each device in the list to a common class SearchData which is then serialized as xml and crawled by our search application.

The service which produces the xml for the search application, takes each item in the device collection and tests its type in order to select the method which should be called to map the device object to a SearchData object:

```
if (device is Radio)
  MapToSearchData(device as Radio);
if (device is TV)
  MapToSearchData(device as TV);
```

While this approach works it doesn't feel like it is the best way to go about mapping objects. Every time a new device type is added to the warehouse the service has to be modified.

What would be the best way to approach the mapping of objects to a common class. Would it be best for the domain objects to have a Map method with their type specific mapping built in?

Comment: "Would it be best for the domain objects to have a Map method with their type specific mapping built in" : Basically yes.

Comment: Hi RedPolygon, thanks for your help